# How to delete message of other bots in Telegram?

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I don't know how to delete messages using telegram BOT API of some bots

Is it possible to delete other bot's messages in telegram using BOT API?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** : It's not possible to delete other bots' messages. Only bot's own messages and user messages can be deleted. Some limitations apply.

<strike>Yes, it is possible to delete messages via bot. Some limitations apply.</strike>

> - A message can only be deleted if it was sent less than 48 hours ago.
> - Bots can delete outgoing messages in groups and supergroups.
> - Bots granted can_post_messages permissions can delete outgoing messages in channels.
> - If the bot is an administrator of a group, it can delete any message there.
> - If the bot has can_delete_messages permission in a supergroup or a channel, it can delete any message there.

See
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage.

Comment: You are wrong. It's not possible to delete messages of other bots

Comment: You are right. Guess the API documentation is somewhat poorly worded at this point. "It can delete any message" is not entirely true. Just tried it myself and it won't let you do it: "Bad Request: message can't be deleted"